# How to read class properties outside of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I've wrote a JS class and I want to make use of jQuery's API but don't know how to read the values outside of the jQuery object.

```
function Slideshow( originalslideshowid, nextslideshowId ) {

    this.originalslideshowId = originalslideshowid;
    this.nextslideshowId = nextslideshowId;

    $("#nextslideshow").click( function(e) {

        hideoriginal( this.originalslideshowId );

    } );

    this.showOriginal = function() {

        $( this.originalslideshow ).click(function(e) {

            shownext(this.nextslideshowId);

        });

    };

};
```

As you can guess, this.originalslideshowId and this.nextslideshowId returns undefined as they are trying to read the properties from within the jQuery object. How can I get them to read the correct properties from the Slideshow class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save `this` to a variable:

```
function Slideshow( originalslideshowid, nextslideshowId ) {
    var _this = this;

    this.originalslideshowId = originalslideshowid;
    this.nextslideshowId = nextslideshowId;

    $("#nextslideshow").click( function(e) {    
        hideoriginal( _this.originalslideshowId );    
    });

    this.showOriginal = function() {    
        $( this.originalslideshow ).click(function(e) {    
            shownext(_this.nextslideshowId);    
        });    
    };    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Been scouring the web for an hour and couldn't find anything about managing the scope in JS and jQuery!